# Move rvm/gems or make available to root

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6, rvm

On a CentOS 6 server I accidentally installed `rvm` and a bunch of gems as non-root user. Everything is running well, however I'll need to run rvm scripts as super user later. I'd like to fix my configuration and make rvm available to root by default.

#### Is it a bad practice if I try to make rvm available for root by default? And is it possible to move rvm and all gems in a clean way to another user (i.e. root)?

I'm not experienced in this field, the options I'm considering are:

1. export the current rvm path to $PATH for root (by editing `etc/rc.d/rc.local`)
2. adding a script to do the same as above but in `etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`
3. remove and reinstall rvm as root

I have a feeling that 1. and 2. will work, but it is not a good approach. Re-installing rvm I'm afraid may mess up some dependencies.

I realize it's a basic question, thank you for your time and understanding in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### I ended up reinstalling rvm.

There is a function to add managers, however it requires that Mult-User is enabled from a super user installation.

From the [RVM guided installation](http://rvm.io/rvm/install):

> - After following above instructions for Multi-User.
> - For each user that want to use RVM, an additional command needs to be
>   run (once) for each user:
>
> `rvm user gemsets`

but the `Multi-User` function should have been enabled first:

> The (Multi-User) rvm function will be automatically configured for every user on
> the system **if you install with sudo**.